# form post by clicking "no submit" button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i got got confused when i run the static js and html below

i want to dynamicly add option by clicking button, but when i put it under the form , it will do acition post, unless i put it out of form ,it works. what's the reason? i didn't set type  as "submit" for the add button, does any button clicked in form will cause form action?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>作业管理</title>

</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" >
  <div id="postform">
    本次作业标题
      <input type="text" name="title" />
      <br>
    <div class="postoption"> 
      添加项目
      <input type="text" name="option[]" />
      音频文件
      <input type="file" name="radio[]" />
      答案
      <input type="text" name="answer[]" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="add">添加输入项</button>
  <input type="submit" value="提交" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function(){
  var add = document.getElementById("add");
  add.onclick = function(){
    addOption();
  }
}
function addOption(){
  var postForm = document.getElementById("postform");
  var postoptions = document.getElementsByClassName("postoption");
  var op = postoptions[0];
  var optionClone = op.cloneNode(true);
  postForm.appendChild(optionClone);
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<button>` element is a submit button by default. You can change this with the `type="button"` attribute, which makes it do nothing by default, or calling `preventDefault` on the event. But I'd go with the attribute since then your intention is semantically clear without actually running the script.